# Site is redirecting to xampp home page when htaccess is used to remove the index.php from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, rewriting

Iam trying to remove the index.php from url. I used .htaccess file to remove this.but it is redirecting to xampp home page.

here my .htaccess code is

RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

```
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance